# Selenium WebDriver does not connect with Firefox 20

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, launch

I'm using selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar .
Launched the hub and
Launched the listener using the following command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\Java.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5557 -browser "browserName=firefox",maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS,javaScriptEnabled=true,TAKES_SCREENSHOT=true
```

A blank Firefox window is opened and then following error is displayed:

```
Execute
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID:         C:\Users\PR~1.GRO\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous768293325561108937webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Creating database schema
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fiddlerhook@fiddler2.com installed in winreg-app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on avg@toolbar installed in winreg-app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on web2pdfextension@web2pdf.adobedotcom installed in winreg-app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
*** LOG addons.manager: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\PR~1.GRO\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous768293325561108937webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found

at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1002
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 844
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 809
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 85
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 117
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 106
at SHL.Test.Selenium.ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in C:\Preethi\vs1\WebTest\SeleniumWebTest\Framework\SHL.Test.Selenium\ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver.cs:line 9
at SHL.Test.Selenium.TestContext..ctor(Action testRun, ITestEnvironment testEnvironment, DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities) in C:\Preethi\vs1\WebTest\SeleniumWebTest\Framework\SHL.Test.Selenium\TestContext.cs:line 31
at SHL.Test.Selenium.TestBase.InitSelenium(DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities, ITestEnvironment testEnvironment, Action testRun) in C:\Preethi\vs1\WebTest\SeleniumWebTest\Framework\SHL.Test.Selenium\TestBase.cs:line 112
```

On debugging, went to Firefox browser add-ons list and found that Firefox webDriver is incompatible with Firefox 20.0
Current Firefox webdirver version is 2.28.0

Which latest Firefox version can I use or is there any alternative for this issue?

Comment: Try Selenium version 2.32.It works fine for Firefox 20.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the latest version instead. for now 2.32.0

see http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
or direct download http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar

it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 20 has only just come out, it will probably take a couple of days for the Selenium devs to fix any compatibility issues that have sprung up.

The latest version of Selenium is 2.31.0 (available [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list)) which will work with Firefox 19.0.2.  Any version of Selenium below 2.30.0 will not work with FireFox 19 and upwards so I would suggest you try updating Selenium to the latest version first.

To be clear I have not yet downloaded and tried FireFox 20 so I don't know how compatible Selenium 2.31.0 is with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. Selenium stopped working after the recent update to 20. I was using Eclipse (JDK 7). I changed Eclipse.ini to use JDK 6 instead and it started working.
Webdriver hangs once in a while but works most of the time(It could be an issue with the website I'm testing as well). To be safe, I have now disabled Firefox auto updates.