# Firefox window is opened but the URL is not placed in the address bar

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am the beginner of the Webdriver.

My script exported from firefox IDE to webdriver is running successfully but the problem I written the very simple script to load the google home page.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 

public class sample { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
       WebDriver test = new FirefoxDriver(); 
       test.get("www.google.com"); 
    }
}
```

What's happening was that the Firefox web-browser is opening but the URL is not sent to the address bar. As a result I am getting an error as shown below:

**Error**

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your complete script!

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class sample {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver test = new FirefoxDriver();
        test.get("www.google.com");
    }

}

Comment: Are you guessing the problem in the script?. I am not getting any error for my script which is exported from selenium IDE from firefox.

Comment: Try to downgrade your Firefox.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352775/org-openqa-selenium-firefox-notconnectedexception-unable-to-connect-to-host-127

Comment: Yes. After downgraded, it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an incompatibility between your firefox- and your selenium-version. Ttry using the latest selenium-java (Version 2.45).

Also note that you have to specify a protocol in your `get`-call:

```
test.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved when i downgraded the Firefox version from latest version to FF 22.0