# URL not typing in firefox

Tags: selenium

I am facing a problem when executing Selenium in Eclipse.

I am using Eclipse Luna, Mozilla Firefox 41 and Selenium 2.48.2. When I try to run this below code, URL is not typing in Firefox.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class first {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675416/firefox-window-is-opened-but-the-url-is-not-placed-in-the-address-bar