# Getting org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException while executing selenium wedriver code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the following `NotConnectedException` while trying to run Selenium Code:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
3a9e97384}","minVersion":"43.0.2","maxVersion":"43.0.2"}],"targetPlatforms":[]}
1451223178321   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
```

I am using Firefox v43.0.2 and Selenium v2.48.2.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Hi Ishan Currently Selenium 2.48.2 support stable version of firefox. I just ran my test cases on firefox 41 version and its working fine. Kindly degrade your firefox version to 41 and run again. You can wait for Selenium new version and then run on 43.

Answer (score 1):

You need to downgrade Firefox or update Selenium.
I think answers and tips mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352775/org-openqa-selenium-firefox-notconnectedexception-unable-to-connect-to-host-127) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Issue is resolved now. Just downgraded the firefox version to 41.0 and now it is working fine.